# What is this paper/foil in between drywall and concrete block? Can I cut it and repair it?

Tags: drywall, vapor-barrier

I want to move an outlet so I cut out a horizontal stretch of drywall and found a layer of paper and foil.  I assume it's some kind of vapor barrier.  What I really need to know is, is it ok to cut it and then tape it?  If so, do I need special tape or can I use regular old "duck" tape?

[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqzoc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The foil is either part of the insulation panels I think I see there or it's a separate product, but the intention is the same. It reflects radiant heat and stifles moisture movement.

You can remove it in small areas without substantially affecting the insulation envelope of your home, but you should attempt to re-seal the area using appropriate materials. Duct tape isn't a good long-term product. I'd use housewrap tape, which has a more durable adhesive and film, or at least a good packaging tape.